# AWS IoT: Shadow not updating

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, iot, aws-iot

I have the pubSub code example working, so I can publish to MQTT topics. And it is my understanding that I just need to change the topic to `"mything/shadow/update"`, and the shadow would be updated, but it doesn't.

My current shadow state looks like:

```
{
  "desired":{
    "welcome": "aws-iot"
  },
  "reported":{
    "welcome": "aws-iot"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you given appropriate permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons why your shadow is not updating. Here might be some.

1. In Cognito, there are no appropriate permissions for Update/Get Shadow both for authenticated and unauthenticated pool
2. The ARN of the Cognito Pool id as well as the IoT are incorrect
3. Check the IAM policy and the following policy to the Cognito users, Also for the Cognito user, you have to attach AttachPrincipalPolicy policy to give them appropriate permissions for Get/update the shadow. The policy below should be in the Cognito Auth and UnAuth roles.

Policy :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
] }
```

To suscribe to changes `$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update/accepted`

And to publish the data to the shadow `$aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update`

Also do check if you are able to connect to the shadow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The changes in Cognito and IAM were uneffective. I am able to see the message on aws/things/thing_name/shadow/update, but not on update/accepted. Still unsure how to fix this.

Comment: is the shadow changing on shadow/update which is to publish? The update/accepted is to get the changed data(subscribe), not to publish

Comment: Yes. When I publish and subscribe to shadow/update I can see the message, but when I subscribe to update/accepted, nothing shows up. So my question is why is it not being accepted. Also when I subscribe to update/rejected nothing shows up either.

Comment: Yes, update/accepted won’t show anything. We are just subscribing to the thing. It is the correct behaviour.

Comment: You would just receive the entire shadow nothing else

Comment: I'm not receiving anything though. And the shadow isn't changing. As I said pub/sub is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "state":{
    "desired":{
      "welcome": "aws-iot"
    }
  }
}
```

try to send like this in shadow/update. worked for me.